# NDSolve DAE solution order is mixed up

Tags: differential-equations, numerical-integration, bugs, options

**Bug introduced in 10.4.0.0 or earlier and fixed in 11.0.1.**

---

Compare the two solution sets below: in the first one (`x == False`), there are only 3 dependent variables while in the second one (`x == True`), a dependent algebraic variable is introduced as `r[t] == 5` (converting the ODE to a DAE). A DAE often requires a different `NDSolve` method, here I used `"EquationSimplification" -> {Automatic, "SimplifySystem" -> True}` which messes up the solution order as is apparent from the plots.

```
ClearAll[t, R, A, P, r, x];
eq = {
      R'[t] == -.1 R[t],
      A'[t] == .1 A[t],
      P'[t] == 0,
      If[x, r[t] == Sin[t], Nothing],
      R[0] == 1, A[0] == 1, P[0] == 1
  };

sol1 = Block[{x = False}, 
   NDSolve[eq, {R, A, P}, {t, 0, 20}, DependentVariables -> {R, A, P}]];
sol2 = Block[{x = True}, 
   NDSolve[eq, {R, A, P, r}, {t, 0, 20}, DependentVariables -> {R, A, P, r}, 
    Method -> {"EquationSimplification" -> {Automatic, 
        "SimplifySystem" -> True}}]];

Grid[{
   LogPlot[#[t] /. sol1, {t, 0, 20}, PlotLabel -> #] & /@ {R, A, P},
   LogPlot[#[t] /. sol2, {t, 0, 20}, PlotLabel -> #] & /@ {R, A, P, r}
}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Can anyone reproduce this bug?

(Mathematica 10.4.0.0, Windows 7, 64bits)

---

TechSupport filed an internal report acknowledging the wrong order of output.

Comment: Removing `DependentVariables -> ... ` in `sol2` will also solve the issue. If `r[t]` is to be regarded as an *algebraic function* it may be more robust to provide initial conditions, e.g. `{ r[0] == 5, r[t] == 5 }`.

Comment: @gwr As a matter of fact, `r` can be any `t`-dependent function like `Sin[t]`, I only left it as a constant for the sake of simplicity. I've edited it into the post.

Comment: Ok, I see, but then the question has been a bit misleading. Also note that the plots do not match your question. :)

Comment: @gwr Thanks for pointing out the discrepancy! My question was specifically about the reproducibility of this bug, though I have not yet added the tag `[bug]` as TS did not confirm it yet.

Comment: Have you gotten any feedback with regard to the `[bug]` tag from TS yet?

Comment: @gwr Nothing explicit yet. I've sent an email to the person I'm in contact with to enquire about any progress/acknowledgement.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems that this might be a *bug* or maybe a *weakness* of the `NDSolve`machinery. One can observe, that with the option `"SimplifySystem" -> False` the issue does not arise. In fact a lot of settings will cause no problem at all.

As far as I can see, the culprit is the option `DependentVariables` as it seems to influence the sequence of equation simplifications somehow. This can be seen here:

```
ClearAll[t, R, A, P, r, x];
With[
    {  eq = {
           R'[t] == -.1 R[t], A'[t] == .1 A[t], P'[t] == 0,
           r[t] == Sin[t],

           r[0] == Sin[0], R[0] == 1, A[0] == 1, P[0] == 1    
       },
       sequences = Permutations@{R, A, P, r} 
    },
    Module[
       {solutions, trials},
       solutions = Map[
           First @ NDSolve[
           eq, 
           {R, A, P, r}, 
           {t, 0, 20}, 
           DependentVariables -> #, (* use the actual permutation *)
           Method -> {"EquationSimplification" -> {Automatic, "SimplifySystem" -> True}}] &
           ,
           sequences
       ];
       trials = Transpose @ { sequences, solutions };
       Apply[
          Function[ {seq, sol} ,
            { 
               Map[ToString] /* StringJoin@ seq,
               Sequence @@ ( 
                 LogPlot[ #[t] /. sol, {t, 0, 20}, PlotLabel -> #, ImageSize -> Tiny, 
                 PlotTheme -> "Minimal"] & /@ {R, A, P, r}
               )
            }
          ],
          trials,
          1
       ] // Multicolumn[#, 3] &
    ]
]
```

> [image: Trials]

We see that of the 24 possible sequences for the dependent variables only 4 produce the correct solution:

> {A,P,R,r} , {A, P, r, R}, {A, r, P, R}, {r, A, P, R}

### Update

This issue seems fixed now:

```
$Version
```

> 11.1.0 for Microsoft Windows (64-bit) (March 13, 2017)

The above code now produces the same results for all permutations of the sequence of variables as it should:

[image: correct results]

Comment: I see, it all hinges on `"SimplifySystem" -> True` as with `False` everthing turns out ok.

Comment: Yes, the internal simplification somehow rotates the list of variables by one to the left, regardless of the number of added algebraic functions (I've tried with more than one such variable).

Comment: @IstvánZachar I do note, that it works out when the option `DependentVariables` is dropped? -- My gut feeling here is *bug*.

Comment: To be honest, it works with any of the option-specifications being dropped : )

Comment: @IstvánZachar It seems that the option `DependentVariables`indeed is the culprit, as the sequence given there influences the equation simplification as can be seen from my updated answer.