# DSolve solution depends on ordering of equation

Tags: differential-equations, bugs

**Bug introduced in 6.0, persisting through 11.1.0 or later, fixed in 12.3.1 or earlier.**

---

I am trying to obtain the general solution, $G(x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4)$ to the very easy system of PDEs:
$$
\partial_{x_3} G(x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4) - \partial_{x_1} F(x_1,x_2) = 0, \\
\partial_{x_4} G(x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4) - \partial_{x_2} F(x_1,x_2) = 0  \label{a}\tag{1}
$$
and in so doing I am finding the following strange behaviour in Mathematica 10.4.

```
DSolve[
{D[G[x1, x2, x3, x4], x3] == D[F[x1, x2], x1],
D[G[x1, x2, x3, x4], x4] == D[F[x1, x2], x2]},
G[x1, x2, x3, x4], {x1, x2, x3, x4}
]
```

returns what I expect:

```
{{G[x1,x2,x3,x4]->C[1][x1,x2]+x4 (F^(0,1))[x1,x2]+x3 (F^(1,0))[x1,x2]}}
```

However, if I just reorder my input:

```
DSolve[
{D[F[x1,x2],x1]==D[G[x1,x2,x3,x4],x3],
D[F[x1,x2],x2]==D[G[x1,x2,x3,x4],x4]},
G[x1,x2,x3,x4],{x1,x2,x3,x4}
]
```

Mathematica returns nothing! This obviously doesn't cause a problem for this simple example. However, the system I get from some other portion of the code is given in the form of (\ref{a}) which, if plugged into DSolve in that form, gives the same null result. This is because if I have Mathematica Simplify the system, I get a system of the second form which gives a null result. I can do something hacky and have it solve for the derivative of $G$ in terms of everything else, but I would prefer to avoid this.

**Update: This is not the only bug of this form in DSolve. It appears the order in which the different equations appear also matters (for 3 or more equations), see e.g. below**

For

```
badPDE = {D[G[x0, x1, y0, y1, z0, z1], z1] == D[F[x0, y0, z0], z0],
D[G[x0, x1, y0, y1, z0, z1], y1] == D[F[x0, y0, z0], y0],
D[G[x0, x1, y0, y1, z0, z1], x1] == D[F[x0, y0, z0], x0]}
```

we get

```
DSolve[badPDE, G, {x0,x1,y0,y1,z0,z1}]
```

failing in the same manner as above, it echos the command. However,

```
DSolve[Reverse[badPDE], G, {x0,x1,y0,y1,z0,z1}]
```

gives the correct answer:

```
{{G->Function[{x0,x1,y0,y1,z0,z1},C[1][x0,y0,z0]+z1 (F^(0,0,1))    
 [x0,y0,z0]+y1 (F^(0,1,0))[x0,y0,z0]+x1 (F^(1,0,0))[x0,y0,z0]]}}
```

I am adding this to my original bug report with WRI.

Comment: A workaround: `DSolve[SortBy[FreeQ[#, G] &] /@ pde, G[x1, x2, x3, x4], {x1, x2, x3, x4}]`.

Comment: Thanks for the workaround @MichaelE2. I really have the expressions in a list with expressions of the form F + G == 0 or F-G==0. If I simplify this I get F+G==0 and F==G respectively. Your workaround works in the later case but not in the former. Is there a way to always get this in the form G == something?

Comment: I see this bug even in Mathematica 8.0.4 I have at hand currently.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a workaround, as requested in a comment and extended to handle the updated problem.  The idea is to solve the pde system for the derivatives so that we can put the derivatives of `G` on the left-hand side of the equation.  There is a hard-coded internal pattern that assumes the problem will be set up this way.  `Solve` returns these in the form of a `Rule`. Replacing `Rule` by `Equal` converts them back to equations, but with the derivatives on the LHS. ***Update:*** Additionally, the hard-coded pattern requires the derivatives of `G` to be in a the same order as the arguments' order, that is, `D[.., x0] ==..`, `D[.., y0] ==..`, `D[.., z0] ==..`.  This can be fixed by sorting the derivatives of `G`.

```
normal[U_] = Function[pde, 
   Reverse@Sort@First@Solve[pde, 
        Cases[Variables[pde /. Equal -> List], _?(! FreeQ[#, U] &)]] /. 
    Rule -> Equal];

DSolve[normal[G]@{D[F[x1, x2], x1] == D[G[x1, x2, x3, x4], x3], 
   D[F[x1, x2], x2] == D[G[x1, x2, x3, x4], x4]}, G, {x1, x2, x3, x4}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

*N.B.* We're assuming we've got a linear first-order pde system here.  (A similar approach could work on higher-order systems, with some work.)

**Example in the update**

```
DSolve[normal[G]@badPDE, G, {x0, x1, y0, y1, z0, z1}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

It seems the internal code assumes in the 3D case that the equations have been set up in the order

```
Grad[G, {x1, y1, z1}] == V /; Curl[V, {x1, y1, z1}] == {0, 0, 0}
```

This suggests this change to `normal`:

```
normal[u_, vars_] = Function[pde, First@Solve[pde, Grad[u, vars]] /. Rule -> Equal];
```

And this change in its usage, with the arguments being specified:

```
normal[G[x0, x1, y0, y1, z0, z1], {x1, y1, z1}]@badPDE
```

Here is another way to use `normal` to fix `DSolve`:

```
ClearAll[gradify];
SetAttributes[gradify, HoldAll];
gradify[code_DSolve] := Internal`InheritedBlock[{DSolve`DSolvePDEs},
  Unprotect[DSolve`DSolvePDEs];
  DSolve`DSolvePDEs[eqs_, {u_}, v : {x_, y_, z_}, c_, i_] := 
   With[{gradeqs = normal[u @@ v, v]@eqs},
    DSolve`DSolvePDEs[gradeqs, {u}, {x, y, z}, c, i] /; gradeqs =!= eqs];
  Protect[DSolve`DSolvePDEs];
  code
  ]
```

Example:

```
gradify@DSolve[badPDE, G, {x0, x1, y0, y1, z0, z1}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Is DSolve`DSolvePDEs documented anywhere?

Comment: @bbgodfrey No, I doubt it. `DSolve` has several special utility solvers for different types of problems, judging from the ``DSolve` `` context.

Answer (score 8):

This looks like a bug.  Clearly the order should not make a difference. Here is another version of the problem. Putting both on the same side

```
lhs1 = D[g[x1, x2, x3, x4], x3];
rhs1 = D[f[x1, x2], x1];
lhs2 = D[g[x1, x2, x3, x4], x4];
rhs2 = D[f[x1, x2], x2];
```

Now

```
 DSolve[{lhs1==rhs1,lhs2==rhs2},g[x1,x2,x3,x4],{x4,x3,x2,x1}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

But

```
 DSolve[{lhs1-rhs1==0,lhs2-rhs2==0},g[x1,x2,x3,x4],{x1,x2,x3,x4}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

In Maple, the order does not affect the result

[image: Mathematica graphics]

I remember seeing issue once where order of variables made difference in result, but this I remember was in integrate not dsolve? may be someone knows about this more.

Comment: I agree it is a bug. I wonder if there's any clever ways around it... Maybe the most clever solution is to use maple for this.

Comment: @JeremyUpsal You should report it to WRI. It appears your PDE system belongs to a special case.  The solver is set up for the equations to be in the order LHS = derivative of unknown, RHS is free of unknown.  A pre-processor ought to be able to rewrite the system in the proper order, but either there isn't one or it fails.  I wouldn't think it would hard for them to fix.

Comment: Nasser and @MichaelE2 see new edit for another similar bug. Again this doesn't have any issues in Maple, although the "bad" arrangement for Mathematica does take longer for Maple to solve than the "good" arrangement, so it is also doing some rearrangement.

Comment: There was an issue with the order of dependent variables in DAE (see [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/114886/764)), but that has been fixed. Not sure, whether that issue is related.

Answer (score 0):

The bug is fixed in *v12.3.1* or earlier:

[image]

BTW the bug is introduced in *v6.0*:

[image]

[image]