# Order of boundary condition inside DSolve matters?

Tags: differential-equations, bugs, symbolic

**Bug introduced in 11.1.1 or earlier, fixed in 12.3.1 or earlier.**

---

Consider the following example:

```
heqn = {Laplacian[u[x, y], {x, y}] + 5 u[x, y] == 0};
bc = {u[x, 0] == UnitTriangle[x - 2], u[0, y] == 0, u[x, 2] == 0, u[4, y] == 0};
DSolve[{heqn, bc}, u[x, y], {x, y}]
(* DSolve returns unevaluated. *)
```

OK, not that surprising, `DSolve` is still weak, but this is actually *almost* an working example in the document of `DSolve`, you can find it under **Scope** -> **Elliptic Partial Differential Equations**. I have only exchange the order of `u[x, 2] == 0` and `u[0, y] == 0` i.e. the following code will work!:

```
heqn = {Laplacian[u[x, y], {x, y}] + 5 u[x, y] == 0};
bc = {u[x, 0] == UnitTriangle[x - 2], u[x, 2] == 0, u[0, y] == 0, u[4, y] == 0}
DSolve[{heqn, bc}, u[x, y], {x, y}]
(* Works as expected. *)
```

So my question is, is this a bug, or a intentional design i.e. I need to make the boundary condition for the same dimension attached etc.?

Comment: This is a known bug, see https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/143726/dsolve-solution-depends-on-ordering-of-equation

Comment: @user58955 They do look similar, but I think the essence of problem may be different, because the workaround given by Michael E2 doesn't work for my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The bug is fixed in *v12.3.1* or earlier:

[image]